Extract (parse) specific strings from a ansible playbook output - bash
I have the following output from a ansible playbook execution.
PLAY [SonarQube on-boarding] ***************************************************

TASK [Create file directory] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "gid": 20, "group": "staff", "mode": "0777", "owner": "abc", "path": "./files", "size": 96, "state": "directory", "uid": 502}

TASK [Create tenants permission structure] *************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "checksum": "d2e330325702090ac3661b7abcf57d1023a758ea", "dest": "./files/tenants.yml", "gid": 20, "group": "staff", "md5sum": "a0277b8826cd362e2782bf0d25b523fd", "mode": "0777", "owner": "abc", "size": 867, "src": "/Users/abc/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1723558954.538402-6040-258956284992736/.source.yml", "state": "file", "uid": 502}

TASK [Dynamic load of variable containing tenant structure] ********************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"temp_var": {"tenant": [{"groupName": "r-docet-admin", "name": "docet", "permission": ["admin"], "status": "present", "target": "admin"}, {"groupName": "r-docet-user", "name": "docet", "permission": ["profileadmin", "provisioning"], "status": "present", "target": "user"}, {"groupName": "r-test_team_b-admin", "name": "test_team_b", "permission": ["profileadmin", "scan"], "status": "present", "target": "admin"}, {"groupName": "r-test_team_b-user", "name": "test_team_b", "permission": ["scan"], "status": "present", "target": "user"}, {"groupName": "r-test_team_a-admin", "name": "test_team_a", "permission": ["profileadmin", "scan"], "status": "present", "target": "admin"}, {"groupName": "r-test_team_a-user", "name": "test_team_a", "permission": ["scan"], "status": "present", "target": "user"}]}}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/Users/abc/git/ansible-play-sonarqube-onboard/files/tenants.yml"], "changed": false}

TASK [Create file directory] ***************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "false_condition": "onboard_action == \"absent\"", "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

TASK [Create tenants permission structure] *************************************
skipping: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "false_condition": "onboard_action == \"absent\"", "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

TASK [Dynamic load of variable containing tenant structure] ********************
skipping: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "false_condition": "onboard_action == \"absent\"", "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}

TASK [sonarqube-onboard : Create Sonarqube Groups] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'test_team_b', 'status': 'present', 'target': 'user', 'permission': ['scan'], 'groupName': 'r-test_team_b-user'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"errors\":[{\"msg\":\"Group \\u0027r-test_team_b-user\\u0027 already exists\"}]}", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Tue, 13 Aug 2024 14:22:43 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": {"groupName": "r-test_team_b-user", "name": "test_team_b", "permission": ["scan"], "status": "present", "target": "user"}, "json": {"errors": [{"msg": "Group 'r-test_team_b-user' already exists"}]}, "msg": "HTTP Error 400: ", "redirected": false, "status": 400, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "transfer_encoding": "chunked", "url": "https://sonarqube.luigi-lab.worldpay.io/api/user_groups/create", "vary": "accept-encoding"}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'test_team_a', 'status': 'present', 'target': 'admin', 'permission': ['profileadmin', 'scan'], 'groupName': 'r-test_team_a-admin'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"errors\":[{\"msg\":\"Group \\u0027r-test_team_a-admin\\u0027 already exists\"}]}", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Tue, 13 Aug 2024 14:22:46 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": {"groupName": "r-test_team_a-admin", "name": "test_team_a", "permission": ["profileadmin", "scan"], "status": "present", "target": "admin"}, "json": {"errors": [{"msg": "Group 'r-test_team_a-admin' already exists"}]}, "msg": "HTTP Error 400: ", "redirected": false, "status": 400, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "transfer_encoding": "chunked", "url": "https://sonarqube.luigi-lab.worldpay.io/api/user_groups/create", "vary": "accept-encoding"}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'test_team_a', 'status': 'present', 'target': 'user', 'permission': ['scan'], 'groupName': 'r-test_team_a-user'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"errors\":[{\"msg\":\"Group \\u0027r-test_team_a-user\\u0027 already exists\"}]}", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Tue, 13 Aug 2024 14:22:47 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": {"groupName": "r-test_team_a-user", "name": "test_team_a", "permission": ["scan"], "status": "present", "target": "user"}, "json": {"errors": [{"msg": "Group 'r-test_team_a-user' already exists"}]}, "msg": "HTTP Error 400: ", "redirected": false, "status": 400, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "transfer_encoding": "chunked", "url": "https://sonarqube.luigi-lab.worldpay.io/api/user_groups/create", "vary": "accept-encoding"}

TASK [sonarqube-onboard : Assign Sonarqube Group Permissions] ******************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'test_team_b', 'status': 'present', 'target': 'user', 'groupName': 'r-test_team_b-user'}, 'scan']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "cookies": {}, "cookies_string": "", "cross_origin_embedder_policy": "require-corp", "cross_origin_opener_policy": "same-origin", "cross_origin_resource_policy": "same-origin", "date": "Tue, 13 Aug 2024 14:22:58 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": [{"groupName": "r-test_team_b-user", "name": "test_team_b", "status": "present", "target": "user"}, "scan"], "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", "redirected": false, "status": 204, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "url": "https://sonarqube.luigi-lab.worldpay.io/api/permissions/add_group", "x_content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff", "x_frame_options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x_webkit_csp": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block"}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'test_team_a', 'status': 'present', 'target': 'admin', 'groupName': 'r-test_team_a-admin'}, 'profileadmin']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "cookies": {}, "cookies_string": "", "cross_origin_embedder_policy": "require-corp", "cross_origin_opener_policy": "same-origin", "cross_origin_resource_policy": "same-origin", "date": "Tue, 13 Aug 2024 14:22:59 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": [{"groupName": "r-test_team_a-admin", "name": "test_team_a", "status": "present", "target": "admin"}, "profileadmin"], "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", "redirected": false, "status": 204, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "url": "https://sonarqube.luigi-lab.worldpay.io/api/permissions/add_group", "x_content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff", "x_frame_options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x_webkit_csp": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block"}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'test_team_a', 'status': 'present', 'target': 'admin', 'groupName': 'r-test_team_a-admin'}, 'scan']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "cookies": {}, "cookies_string": "", "cross_origin_embedder_policy": "require-corp", "cross_origin_opener_policy": "same-origin", "cross_origin_resource_policy": "same-origin", "date": "Tue, 13 Aug 2024 14:23:01 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": [{"groupName": "r-test_team_a-admin", "name": "test_team_a", "status": "present", "target": "admin"}, "scan"], "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", "redirected": false, "status": 204, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "url": "https://sonarqube.luigi-lab.worldpay.io/api/permissions/add_group", "x_content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff", "x_frame_options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x_webkit_csp": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block"}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'test_team_a', 'status': 'present', 'target': 'user', 'groupName': 'r-test_team_a-user'}, 'scan']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "cookies": {}, "cookies_string": "", "cross_origin_embedder_policy": "require-corp", "cross_origin_opener_policy": "same-origin", "cross_origin_resource_policy": "same-origin", "date": "Tue, 13 Aug 2024 14:23:02 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "item": [{"groupName": "r-test_team_a-user", "name": "test_team_a", "status": "present", "target": "user"}, "scan"], "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", "redirected": false, "status": 204, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "url": "https://sonarqube.luigi-lab.worldpay.io/api/permissions/add_group", "x_content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff", "x_frame_options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x_webkit_csp": "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self' http: https:; img-src * data: blob:; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; worker-src 'none'", "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0   



I want to verify that changed = to more than 0 and under TASK [Create tenants permission structure] "changed" is defined as true.
Also under TASK [sonarqube-onboard : Create Sonarqube Groups], for all items with name test_team_b I want to verify 'status' is defined as  'present'
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Please clarify.

[edit] your question to show the expected output plus your attempt to solve your problem, see [ask] and in particular the part about creating a [mcve].

The best way to handle this IMO is to switch your output plugin to yaml or json and parse the stats with a tool like jq or yq.
Dummy example
Given the following inventory:
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    test1:
    test2:

And the following playbook:
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: echo toto

Which you can execute forcing the output as json with:
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=ansible.posix.json ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml example.yml

You get the following raw result:
{
    "custom_stats": {},
    "global_custom_stats": {},
    "plays": [
        {
            "play": {
                "duration": {
                    "end": "2024-08-13T16:08:58.760835Z",
                    "start": "2024-08-13T16:08:58.451673Z"
                },
                "id": "519e7ea9-39cf-1a01-4b04-000000000003",
                "name": "all",
                "path": "/tmp/example.yml:2"
            },
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "hosts": {
                        "test1": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": null,
                            "action": "shell",
                            "changed": true,
                            "cmd": "echo toto",
                            "delta": "0:00:00.005336",
                            "end": "2024-08-13 18:08:58.703006",
                            "invocation": {
                                "module_args": {
                                    "_raw_params": "echo toto",
                                    "_uses_shell": true,
                                    "argv": null,
                                    "chdir": null,
                                    "creates": null,
                                    "executable": null,
                                    "expand_argument_vars": true,
                                    "removes": null,
                                    "stdin": null,
                                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                                    "strip_empty_ends": true
                                }
                            },
                            "msg": "",
                            "rc": 0,
                            "start": "2024-08-13 18:08:58.697670",
                            "stderr": "",
                            "stderr_lines": [],
                            "stdout": "toto",
                            "stdout_lines": [
                                "toto"
                            ]
                        },
                        "test2": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": null,
                            "action": "shell",
                            "changed": true,
                            "cmd": "echo toto",
                            "delta": "0:00:00.003842",
                            "end": "2024-08-13 18:08:58.736638",
                            "invocation": {
                                "module_args": {
                                    "_raw_params": "echo toto",
                                    "_uses_shell": true,
                                    "argv": null,
                                    "chdir": null,
                                    "creates": null,
                                    "executable": null,
                                    "expand_argument_vars": true,
                                    "removes": null,
                                    "stdin": null,
                                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                                    "strip_empty_ends": true
                                }
                            },
                            "msg": "",
                            "rc": 0,
                            "start": "2024-08-13 18:08:58.732796",
                            "stderr": "",
                            "stderr_lines": [],
                            "stdout": "toto",
                            "stdout_lines": [
                                "toto"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "task": {
                        "duration": {
                            "end": "2024-08-13T16:08:58.760835Z",
                            "start": "2024-08-13T16:08:58.458733Z"
                        },
                        "id": "519e7ea9-39cf-1a01-4b04-000000000005",
                        "name": "shell",
                        "path": "/tmp/example.yml:5"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "stats": {
        "test1": {
            "changed": 1,
            "failures": 0,
            "ignored": 0,
            "ok": 1,
            "rescued": 0,
            "skipped": 0,
            "unreachable": 0
        },
        "test2": {
            "changed": 1,
            "failures": 0,
            "ignored": 0,
            "ok": 1,
            "rescued": 0,
            "skipped": 0,
            "unreachable": 0
        }
    }
}


From there it is easy to e.g. extract the number of changes for each host and sum them up with jq:
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=ansible.posix.json ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml example.yml \
| jq '.stats | map(.changed) | add'
2

Since the entire output is json, you can check for whatever you want elsewhere.
